# How do I export eviews workfile in R?

Tags: r, export, eviews

I need to work with a matrix made in eviews, is there any way to load or export in **R**, eviews workfiles or data base and work with this in **R**?

Answer (score 2):

A quick google for `import eviews into r` lead me to the [`hexView` package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hexView/), this supports reading binary EViews files. Alternatively, you could dump the file into an ASCII format, say csv, and read that into R using `read.table`.

Comment: use the package hexView but does not work, because I can not read the matrix made in eviews. HexView only read eviews vectors

Answer (score 1):

EViews has the ability to open up an R session and send data over to R (and execute R commands/scripts too).

Setting EViews up to work with R can be a little tricky, but if you just install the RAndFriends package, it can be done easily enough.

Once setup, you simply need a few EViews commands such as:

```
xopen(r)
xput myobject
```

You can then run R commands on that object from within EViews, or issue an R command to save the object as a native R object, then open up R and access it.

Of course, all of that assumes that you have EViews installed.  Without EViews installed, you're probably out of luck.  Their data format is notoriously difficult to get at.